# Munich LME recipe conversion?

Tags: extract, lme

I would like to make the Maibock recipe from Brewing Classic Styles.  It calls for Munich LME.

1) Does anybody know where I can get my hands on some 100% Munich LME?

2) If I can't get 100% Munich, Jamil Zainasheff says (http://www.thebrewingnetwork.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=&t=9430) I can use the Munich LME that I've found on even though it's a 50/50 blend of Munich and base malts. So if the Recipe calls for 8 lbs Pilsener LME and 4 lbs of Munich, I could use 8 lbs of the Munich Blend, and 4 lbs of the Pilsener.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) William's Brewing carries it at the moment.  It's 50% Munich and 50% pils.

2).  Correct

Comment: So, Williams is not carrying 100% munich LME, they have a 50/50 extract is what you are saying.